# How to remove the styling SFMC adds to freeform Content Blocks?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We are currently developing each email we send out,  using Litmus to confirm that emails render properly. 
I would like to leverage Marketing Cloud's content blocks feature for end-users to easily drag, drop, and modify the content so that I'm not wasting time developing each email.
The problem is, every time I drag a freeform content block over SFMC wraps the content with their own class, and this has resulted in a large amount of padding around each block when rendered in older versions of outlook.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
            <div style="Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
                [My actual code here]
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would suggest testing with an HTML block or a code snippet

Comment: The goal is for my end users to easily drag and drop blocks and build emails themselves. Salesforce sold this idea that you can drag and drop to create emails easily, is this not a reality?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t prevent Salesforce Marketing Cloud from adding their own code to the free form (and other) blocks; however you can take control of how those blocks display by making your own HTML Template.

When you make your own email template you can specify the styles/classes. Get the names of the classes (as you’ve already done) and make new styles for them in your own style sheet. Use the “!important” tag to ensure your styles are followed.

Salesforce does offer “one size fits all” drag and drop functionality; however more advanced formatting/display options are achievable when you make your own code blocks. This is the same for all enterprise email marketing platforms.